# Commit latest release of Git repository into another repository

Tags: git, github

We have two repositories `development` and `customer`.

The latter contains only official releases without all the snarky comments developers have in their commits on the way.

So my question is what is the easiest way to checkout a tag `version` from developer and commit it as the same `version` tag into `customer`?

My current idea would be:

1. checkout `customer` master branch into `cust_dir`
2. checkout `development` version tag in another directory `dev_dir`
3. copy files over from `dev_dir` to `cust_dir` (without .git)
4. git commit/push to `customer`
5. tag `customer` with `version`

..but I can't help feeling there should be an easier way!

I'm only asking this as whilst we have developer documentation, someone left this out.

Comment: The simplest way would be to educate your developers to write polite commit messages, then you wouldn't have to synchronize...

Comment: Whilst I agree, we don't particularly want the entire log exposed anyway, and posters of those messages are no longer with us

Comment: your idea would work though.. I don't see an easy solution around...